# Loading child module context in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm having some issues while accessing the services of spring boot. I have two projects called "Parent Project" and Second is a Child Project. Child project added in Parent Project as a module project. So the issue is when i try to access the Parent project it works fine but it gives me error when i try access the child project services

**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.Wed Apr 13 22:29:30 PKT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available**

Here is a code of both Projects
**Parent Project**

**Example.java**

```
package com.pos.dashboard.backend;
@RequestMapping("/test/**")
@RestController
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

**HelloWorldApplication.java**

```
    package com.pos.dashboard.backend;
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class HelloWorldApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
        }
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dashboard</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.pos.interfaces</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<properties>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
    <start-class>com.pos.dashboard.backend.HelloWorldApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


</dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
    </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>jira-widget-app</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**Child Project**

**Example.java**

```
package com.jira.pos.widget;
@RequestMapping("/tester/**")
@RestController
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public String index() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

**HelloWorldApplication1.java**

```
  package com.jira.pos.widget;
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class HelloWorldApplication1 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication1.class, args);
        }
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>dashboard</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.pos.interfaces</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>jira-widget-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
    <start-class>com.jira.pos.widget.HelloWorldApplication1</start-class>
    </properties>
</project>
```

When i try to access http://localhost:8080/test
it returns me Hello World on browser

However, when i try to access http://localhost:8080/tester
it Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Apr 13 22:37:17 PKT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Can you please include packages?

Comment: package has been added in code

Answer (score -1):

Parent project scans Spring beans in current package and its sub-packages. This is in your case `com.pos.dashboard.backend`.

You have two options (**only one of them should be needed**):

1. Change root package of child project to something like `com.pos.dashboard.backend.child` so that it will be scanned by parent JAR module
2. Include packages from child module into parent component scanning:

   ```
   package com.pos.dashboard.backend;
   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan({"com.pos.dashboard.backend", "com.jira.pos.widget"})
   @EnableAutoConfiguration
   public class HelloWorldApplication {
   ```

BTW, child `@EnableAutoConfiguration` is redundant if it is not used as standalone Spring Boot application.

**Reaction on comment:**

Oh, I also missed that you don't have child project as Maven dependency of parent one. Maven multi-module project creates JAR for each module. in your case you have parent module (that is at the same time also multi module Maven parent) and child module.

I suggest to create third Maven pom purely for multi module setup and have two modules (your parent and child project). Of course you need to include child project and maven dependency into parent project.

[This is very good tutorial for creating multi module projects.](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made changes based on your suggestion
1) change the child module package com.pos.dashboard.backend.child
2) add the following package as component scan in parent module but still no luck yet..

Comment: '@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.pos.dashboard.backend", "com.pos.dashboard.backend.child"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class HelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
        SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldApplication.class, args);
       
    }'

Comment: Sorry maybe my answer was confusing. Only one option was needed. Not both. If you changed all the packages in child module (option 1), `@ComponentScan` attributes should not be necessary (option 2).

Comment: Sorry about that. i'm stick with second optiion but still localhost:8080/api works but http://localhost:8080/tester doesn't.
Is there anyway that i can send you code? It has only four classes

Comment: Ok correct me if i'm wrong 
As of now, i have two projects
Child Project (jira-widget-app)
Parent Project (pos-interfaces-dashboard))
Parent have dependency of child like 
<modules>
  <module>jira-widget-app</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

So you want me to create another project which will have dependency of parent project(pos-interfaces-dashboard)

Let say new project called Main-Application then it'll have 
<modules>
  <module>pos-interfaces-dashboard</module>
</modules>

or 

<modules>
  <module>pos-interfaces-dashboard</module>
  <module>jira-widget-app</module>
</modules>

Comment: Still having same issues. One service is accessible whereas other service doesn't.